# why circular slider is not working with right swipe gesture in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am using circular slider in three classes.where i am moving from one view to another view with swipe left or right Gesture.
I am using below code to add circular slider in view.

```
//add circular meter
   CircularSliderView  *sliderView = [[CircularSliderView alloc] initWithMinValue:0 maxValue:100 initialValue:0];
sliderView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
sliderView.frame=CGRectMake(self.iv_meter.frame.origin.x,self.iv_meter.frame.origin.y, self.iv_meter.frame.size.width, self.iv_meter.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:sliderView];
```

After Moving to another view when i am coming back to previous view then circular Slider is not Working in previous class.where i am right now.

Anyone please suggest me for this.

Answer (score 0):

Take in consideration that if you are adding the CircularSliderView in viewDidLoad when you come back from another controller, viewDidLoad never runs.

**How it works**:

1- If view doesn't exist then it's created and it runs **ViewDidLoad**
2- runs **ViewWillAppear**
3- runs **ViewDidAppear**

In your case you should put your code in **ViewDidAppear** since **VIEW** exist and **ViewDidLoad** doesn't run again.

Hope it helps